# Use array_multisort() with custom function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array and I would like to sort it according another array and not `DESC` or `ASC`

```
$array = array(
    'note' => array('test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'),
    'year' => array('2011','2010', '2012', '2009', '2010'),
    'type' => array('journal', 'conference', 'conference', 'conference','conference'),
);
```

Is it possible to do it with a custom function inside an array_multisort()?

For example:

```
array_multisort($array['type'], $array['year'], custom_function, $array['note']);
```

instead of:

```
array_multisort($array['type'], $array['year'], SORT_ASC, $array['note']);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the depth of the array you can simply apply [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) on each array element to be sorted.

Here is an example which orders according to a custom array:

```
<?php
$order = array(
    'first',
    'second',
    'third',
    'fourth',
    'fifth'
);

$array = array(
    array(
        'second',
        'fourth',
        'first',
        'third'
    ),
    array(
        'second',
        'first'
    )
);

foreach($array as &$value) {
    usort($value, function($a, $b) use($order) {
        return array_search($a, $order) > array_search($b, $order);
    });
}
unset($value);

var_dump($array);
/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "first"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "second"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "third"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "fourth"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "first"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "second"
  }
}
*/
```

If you don't know how deep the array can go, the only solution that comes to my mind is a recursive function:

```
<?php
$order = array(
    'first',
    'second',
    'third',
    'fourth',
    'fifth'
);

$array = array(
    array(
        'second',
        'fourth',
        'first',
        'third'
    ),
    array(
        array('second', 'first'),
        array('fourth', 'third')
    )
);

function custom_multisort($array, $order) {
    foreach($array as &$value) {
        if(is_array($value[0])) {
            $value = custom_multisort($value, $order);
        } else {
            usort($value, function($a, $b) use($order) {
                return array_search($a, $order) > array_search($b, $order);
            });
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

$array = custom_multisort($array, $order);

var_dump($array);
/*
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "first"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "second"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "third"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "fourth"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "first"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "second"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "third"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "fourth"
    }
  }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP's question, assuming that the array lengths are equal, then the following function should work:

```
function uarray_multisort(array &$array1, callable $callback, mixed &...$rest) {
  uasort($array1, $callback);
  $order = array_keys($array1);
  foreach($rest as $arrayN) {
    foreach ($order as $index) {
      $arrayN[] = $arrayN[$index];
    }
    array_splice($arrayN, 0, count($order));
  }
}
```

An example using `uarray_multisort` given the OP's data, noting that the first parameter to uarray_multisort takes a single array, so a temporary array needs to be created from the inputs:

```
$array = array(
  'note' => array('test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'),
  'year' => array('2011', '2010', '2012', '2009', '2010'),
  'type' => array('journal', 'conference', 'conference', 'conference', 'conference'),
);
function custom_function($a, $b) {
  $cmp = $a['year'] - $b['year'];
  return $cmp !== 0 ? $cmp : strcmp($a['type'], $b['type']);
}
$yearType = array_map(function($year, $type){
  return array('year'=>$year, 'type'=>$type);
}, $array['year'], $array['type']);

uarray_multisort($yearType, 'custom_function', $array['note'], $array['year'], $array['type']);
```

Answer (score -4):

I think its not possible.
Instead of that do like this

```
$custom_function_value = custom_function();
array_multisort($array['type'], $array['year'], $custom_function_value, $array['note']);
```

I think this will give your desired output.

Comment: Do you know what values I am allowed to put there? -1, 0 , 1 ?